# macOS SwiftUI: Share DocumentGroup's modelContext with separate WindowGroup

Tags: macos, swiftui, swift-data

I have a SwiftUI document app for macOS with SwiftData storage. The DocumentGroup automatically injects a ModelContext to the environment of it's editor view. Now I want to have a separate window whose view also uses the same ModelContext. Is this possible?

```
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(editing: .itemDocument, migrationPlan: ExampleAppMigrationPlan.self) {
            EditorView()
            /**************************************************
             * ModelContext is automatically injected here
             **************************************************/
        }
        WindowGroup(id: "ToolsWindow") {
            ToolsView()
            /**************************************************
             * How to access ModelContext here?
             **************************************************/
        }
    }
}

struct EditorView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Tools") {
            openWindow(id: "ToolsWindow")
        }
    }
}

struct ToolsView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tools")
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work when each document holds its own model container and context but the tools window can be open separately? What if you have multiple documents open but only one tools window or closes the document where you opened the tools window from?